# Sum of a groupby dataframe not equal to the sum of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have no clue why this is hapening. These are the facts;
1 - I have a real life Dataframe that is really, really messy.

```
A         B                c
John      1/10/2018        100,00
Mark      NA               50,00
          2/09/2018        30,00
Susan     8/10/2018        NA
Mark      8/10/2018        10,00
John      1/10/2018        20,00
NA        NA               40,00
```

Consider that columns B is already set to Datetime and column C is already set to a float.

So, the sum of this dataframe is 250,00

```
df['c'].sum()
```

When I do a groupby, I get another result which is lower

```
df2 = df.groupby('c').sum()
```

I get a value that is lower. What I want is to have a df like this:

```
B                c
2/09/2018        30,00
1/10/2018        120,00
8/10/2018        10,00
NA               90,00
```

Tks for the help!!!

Comment: Are you sure `df2 = df.groupby('c').sum()` ?

Comment: sorry, df2 = df.groupby['c'].reset_index()     thes df2['c'].sum()

Comment: Do you think `df.groupby('b')['c'].sum()` vs `df['c'].sum()`? Because if use  `df.groupby('c').sum()` it grouping by column `c`, so output have to be different like grouping by column `b` with aggregate `c`.